# После пересборки Qt что нужно делать?

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, qt5

Ситуация такова. Пересобрал Qt5.5.1 из исходников под MSVS2015 (версия принципиальна). Конфигурирование происходило с кастомным префиксом установки "-prefix=<путь>". Как и что нужно копировать в этот "префикс"? И как это делать правильно, чтобы всё работало?

Comment: Ничего копировать не надо. Надо выполнить `make install`.

Comment: @kff , Эта операция уже была выполнена. Вот только когда в Qt Creator захожу, добавляю комплекты/профили, мне среда выдает: "Неустановленная сборка настроенная с параметром -prefix предназначена для внутренних целей."
А во время сборки шаблонного проекта он вообще nmake не находит. А ведь он есть.